# Android app fail http request after 5 min usage

Tags: android, retrofit, httpclient

My users say, after 5 min every request failed. But after restart app, application work smoothly. I search everything but not found this error.

This is my OkHttpClient.Builder init code.

```
var builder = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        writeTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
        authenticator(tokenAuthenticator)
    }
```

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30

And this is my retrofit build code

```
return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
        baseUrl(urlConfigHelper.getBaseUrl())
        addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        client(okHttpClient)
    }.build()
```

Xiaomi redmi note 7 android 10 device

This bug not my all users. Just very few person see this bug.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's already added and I think this flag just help http and https security problem for new android security rules. Also my test api with http and prod base url is https.

Comment: you need to test it and check your logcat errors

Comment: I wish but I cant see log messages. My test device not trigger this problem. And I check all Crashlytics messages and cant found anything related.